# How ypass, and unkothis little program

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem with the program is that i it will tell me my variable called "guess" isnI will
Here is the n of saying "Guess lower".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  F
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hfdg'
```

And here is the code for the program

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
tries = 0


print ("Enter yes, or no")

saysalse

while not says_yes or not says_no:
    player_input = input("Would you like to play a game?: ")
    player_input = player_input.lower()
    if player_input == "yes":
        says_yes = True
        break
    elif player_input == "no":
        says_no = True
        print("See you next time.")
        exit()

if says_yes:
    print("Ok, great.")
    print("How this game works is that you are going to guess a number ranging from 1-10 \
and if you guess it right then you win")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
choose a number between 1-10.")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))

while int(guess) != int(random_number):
     tries to guess the number.")
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

```
if says_yes:
    print("Ok, great.")
    print("How this game works is that you are going to guess a number ranging from 1-10 \
and if you guess it right then you win")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))

while guess > 10 or guess < 1:
    print("Please choose a number between 1-10.")
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
```

Pycharm says that error, because it can happen that "says_yes" ist False and the input will noch appear, then guess is not defined, i know you have an exit() but pycharm is pernickety.

HERE YOUR FULL CODE:

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
tries = 0

print("Enter yes, or no")

says_yes = False
says_no = False

while not says_yes or not says_no:
    player_input = input("Would you like to play a game?: ")
    player_input = player_input.lower().strip()
    if player_input == "yes":
        says_yes = True
        break
    elif player_input == "no":
        says_no = True
        print("See you next time.")
        exit()
    else:
        print("You have to think about it again!")

if says_yes:
    print("Ok, great.")
    print("How this game works is that you are going to guess a number ranging from 1-10 and if you guess"
          " it right then you win")
    while True:
        raw_guess = input("Guess a number: ")
        try:
            guess = int(raw_guess)
        except ValueError:
            print("Try it again, this was not a number!")
        else:
            if guess > 10 or guess < 1:
                print("Please choose a number between 1-10.")
            elif guess > random_number:
                print("Guess lower")
                tries += 1
            elif guess < random_number:
                print("Guess higher")
                tries += 1
            else:
                break

print("It took you " + str(tries) + " tries to guess the number.")
```

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. I think now (with the updated version of answer). I answer all your questions. Try the new full code version! :)

Comment: I like that you use string.lower() in the beginning, that is a nice move! I add a string.strip() function for typing something like " yes" or "no ", so with spaces.

Comment: In your version, your:

says_yes = False
says_no = False

while not says_yes or not says_no:

makes no sense, because "break" and "exit()" will stop that while loop. In my version i add an else, so the will loop can work.

Comment: if you convert an string to an integer with int(), and you have letters in the string, so in your work, when you write characters instead of numbers, then you get this ValueError. So with a "try and exept" you can prevent crashing script and let the user try input again. For more information just google for "try and except python"

Comment: "And lastly, when I get to the part when it asks to guess a number, and if I enter in the wrong number, then the program will go through an infinite loop of saying "Guess lower"." - That was a bigger problem, i fixed it and maybe it is only enough for you to look at the solution to understand it. For me it is just 3:00 am at night, I would tell you otherwise later. :)
But do not be afraid to ask everything.